# Powershell XML grouping by multiple levels

Tags: xml, powershell, grouping

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<XML>
    <Series key="A">
        <Observation>
           <Dimension value="2018-11-01" />
           <Value value="123" />
        </Observation>
        <Observation>
           <Dimension value="2018-11-02" />
           <Value value="456" />
        </Observation>
        <Observation>
           <Dimension value="2018-12-01" />
           <Value value="789" />
        </Observation>
        <Observation>
           <Dimension value="2018-12-02" />
           <Value value="222" />
        </Observation>
    </Series>
    <Series key="B">
        <Observation>
           <Dimension value="2018-11-01" />
           <Value value="123" />
        </Observation>
        <Observation>
           <Dimension value="2018-11-02" />
           <Value value="456" />
        </Observation>
        <Observation>
           <Dimension value="2018-12-01" />
           <Value value="789" />
        </Observation>
        <Observation>
           <Dimension value="2018-12-02" />
           <Value value="222" />
        </Observation>
    </Series>
</XML>
```

I want to group the XML per `Series` and per month of the `value`-Attribute of each contained `Dimension`.

I already know how to group by month:

```
$doc.SelectNodes("//Series/Observation", $ns) | Group-Object { $_.Dimension.value.Substring(0,7) }
```

But this results in only 2 groups `2018-11` and `2018-12`. However, I need 4 groups, 2 for each `Series`. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference the `ParentNode` property as the first property to group by:

```
$doc.SelectNodes('//Series/Observation') | Group-Object { $_.ParentNode.key },{ $_.Dimension.value.Substring(0,7) } -NoElement
```

and you will get a result like:

```
Count Name
----- ----
    2 A, 2018-11
    2 A, 2018-12
    2 B, 2018-11
    2 B, 2018-12
```